# Generate Dynamic Update Statement via TSQL

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with a number of columns:

```
col1
col2
col3
coln....
```

I need to generate dynamic `UPDATE` statement like below which will be used in production for bulk update:

```
UPDATE TableA
SET TableA.ColA = ValueOfCol2
WHERE
   TableA.ColB='A'
```

Could anyone please share a TSQL script that generate n number of `UPDATE` statement as above, please?

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of `WHERE TableA='A'`?

Comment: What are you trying to test for here??? `WHERE TableA = 'A'` ?? You cannot just "test" a table name against a fixed value......

Comment: my apologies, it was a typo. I've updated the query

Comment: If this is for a _production_ update, I think you'll need to explain what you want quite a bit clearer, probably show the schema and explain in words what you want done.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your problem, your example code works:

```
UPDATE [updateDemo] SET [updateDemo].[col2] = [updateDemo].[col3] WHERE [col4] = 'A'
```

This is based on the assumption that your table is something like this:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
1      P      Z      A
2      Y      Z      A
3      K      S      V
```

This above update query would result in (changes in square brackets):

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
1      [Z]    Z      A
2      [Z]    Z      A
3      K      S      V
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, I've updated my question title as Dyanmic SQl. I need to be able to generate dyanic update statement based on n Number of records